# Why am I getting 'x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (319,)' when the x and y shapes are same?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, curve-fitting, lmfit

I am using the lmfit package to fit a double exponential function to my data. I am first taking in the x and y coordinate values from a CSV file and plotting them. It works fine. Secondly, I am defining a double_exponential function, and using the lmfit package, I am plotting the double_exponential function against my data.
I have printed out the length of my x and y values (length=319) and also its shapes to see if they match (319,). They do!. But I am still getting an 'x and y must have the same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (319,) ' error. I have attached the code below. Any suggestions in resolving this problem would help.

```
xData=[]
yData=[]
for file in files:
        basename = os.path.basename(file)
        file_name = os.path.splitext(basename)[0]
        # print(file_name)
        #File_List.append(file_name)

        with open(file, "r") as f_in:
            reader = csv.reader(f_in)
            next(reader)
            next(reader)
            for line in reader:
                try:
                    float_1, float_2 = float(line[0]), float(line[1])
                    xData=np.append(xData,float_1)
                    yData=np.append(yData,float_2)                  
                except ValueError:
                    continue
        xData = np.array(xData)
        yData = np.array(yData)
        plt.plot(xData,yData)
        plt.show()
        def double_exp(a,t,T):
            return a*np.exp(-t/T)
        print(xData.shape)
        print(yData.shape)        
        mod = Model(double_exp)
        result = mod.fit(yData,x=xData, a=1, t=1, T=1)
        result.plot()            
        xData=[]
        yData=[]
```

My traceback error is:

```
(319,)
(319,)

C:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\lmfit\model.py:968: UserWarning: The keyword argument x does not match any arguments of the model function. It will be ignored.
  warnings.warn("The keyword argument %s does not " % name +
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-085a1a8ec72a> in <module>
     35         mod = Model(double_exp)
     36         result = mod.fit(yData,x=xData, a=1, t=1, T=1)
---> 37         result.plot()
     38 
     39 

C:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\lmfit\model.py in wrapper(*args, **kws)
     48         @wraps(function)
     49         def wrapper(*args, **kws):
---> 50             return function(*args, **kws)
     51         return wrapper
     52 

C:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\lmfit\model.py in plot(self, datafmt, fitfmt, initfmt, xlabel, ylabel, yerr, numpoints, fig, data_kws, fit_kws, init_kws, ax_res_kws, ax_fit_kws, fig_kws, show_init, parse_complex)
   2115         ax_fit = fig.add_subplot(gs[1], sharex=ax_res, **ax_fit_kws)
   2116 
-> 2117         self.plot_fit(ax=ax_fit, datafmt=datafmt, fitfmt=fitfmt, yerr=yerr,
   2118                       initfmt=initfmt, xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel,
   2119                       numpoints=numpoints, data_kws=data_kws,

C:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\lmfit\model.py in wrapper(*args, **kws)
     48         @wraps(function)
     49         def wrapper(*args, **kws):
---> 50             return function(*args, **kws)
     51         return wrapper
     52 

C:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\lmfit\model.py in plot_fit(self, ax, datafmt, fitfmt, initfmt, xlabel, ylabel, yerr, numpoints, data_kws, fit_kws, init_kws, ax_kws, show_init, parse_complex)
   1890                         fmt=datafmt, label='data', **data_kws)
   1891         else:
-> 1892             ax.plot(x_array, reduce_complex(self.data),
   1893                     datafmt, label='data', **data_kws)
   1894 

C:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1741         """
   1742         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1743         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1744         for line in lines:
   1745             self.add_line(line)

C:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in __call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    271                 this += args[0],
    272                 args = args[1:]
--> 273             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    274 
    275     def get_next_color(self):

C:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    397 
    398         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 399             raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    400                              f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
    401         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (319,)
```

Comment: You initialize `xData` and `yData` with an empty list and then use `np.append` to append more values. Are you sure that both arrays have two dimensions, i.e., `shape==(319,)` including that comma?

Comment: Examine `x` more carefully.If dtype is object, then it contains an array or list.

Comment: Do not use `np.append`.  It is slow and often produces errors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please trim your code and include data so as to have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include a [*complete* error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough), formatted as code Also make very sure that you are checking the shapes *of the arrays you are actually using*, *at the point where they will be used and cause the error*.

Comment: In particular, when you create your minimal reproducible example, check whether you are able to make the code work with hard-coded data (i.e. something is wrong with how the data is loaded from file) or not.

Comment: @applesoup yes it is

Comment: @hpaulj I am getting numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append error otherwise. Thats why I have used np.append

Comment: List's have an append method.  `np.append` looks similar, but because of how arrays are stored, is a poor substitute.

Comment: `files` is not defined, among others. You need to provide a [mre]. Try including your data within your code, instead of loading it from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message tells you exactly what the problem is:

```
UserWarning: The keyword argument x does not match any arguments of the model function. It will be ignored.
```

You supply a value for `x=xData` to the `fit` method, but your function `doubl_exp` does not contain this variable. Here, as in the various other questions you asked about `lmfit`, the best advice is: read the documentation and look at the provided examples on the website. They'll likely cover >95% of your use-case and after that reading the error message Python gives you is always helpful ;)